# Does CSS @font-face supports single dot notation?

Tags: css, url, font-face

For example, if I declare a font-face like this

```
@font-face {        
  font-family: "Flaticon";
  src: url("./flaticon.eot");
}
```

where the file `flaticon.eot` resides in the same directory as the CSS file.
It seems like the url can't be resolved. what is the explanation behind this ?

Comment: The docs say *the URL may be relative, in which case it is resolved relative to the location of the style sheet containing the @font-face rule.*

Comment: If the file `fileicon.eot` resides in the same directory as the css file. Then just use the name of the file as the src url  .. `src: url("flaticon.eot");` https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-3/#src-desc

Comment: What happens when you try it?